# Customizing TokenEndpoint in Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring-oauth2

First of all, I have already went through the previous questions on this subject.

I am trying to customize implementations of org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint and CheckTokenEndpoint.  I can easily do that but I don't know how to plug that customized implementation in Spring Oauth2 Architecture.  I am using @EnableAuthorizationServer annotation in my application.  Could someone shed some light?

Answer (score 2):

Look at AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration class.
There are @Bean definitions of endpoints.
Try to register your endpoint definition beans with the same names and register them as @Primary @Bean

i.e

```
@Primary
@Bean
public CustomTokenEndpoint tokenEndpoint() throws Exception {
...
}
```