# How to make requests to an endpoint to be authorised by client id and secret in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

By default when OAuth2 authorisation is enabled in Spring framework (see the configuration below) and we make a call to `/oauth/token` to issue an access token, the following request is being sent:

```
POST /oauth/token
Authorization: Basic Y34tcF9ib3VpOg==

POST data:
grant_type=password&username=myuser&password=mypass
```

The basic authorisation above is client-id and client's secret in the following form:

myclient:secret123

I can then send this request to Spring's `/oauth/check_token`:

```
POST /oauth/check_token
Authorization: Basic Y34tcF9ib3VpOg==

POST data:
token=the_token_retrieved_from_last_request
```

This works fine and it does basic authorisation before serving my request.

Note that the basic authorisation here goes to Spring's `JdbcClientDetailsService` in which it looks up a table named `oauth_client_details`, this is fine too.

Now for some reason I need to have a customised endpoint instead of Spring's /token/check_access. So I have created a controller similar to the Spring's `CheckTokenEndpoint.java` and named it `TokenIntrospectionEndpoint`. The URL pattern for my endpoint is set to be `/oauth/introspect`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/oauth")
public class TokenIntrospectionEndpointImpl {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/introspect")
    @ResponseBody
    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> introspect(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        // return data
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, the request to this endpoint is being served without considering basic authorisation. So I've added this line in the configuration:

```
   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
       .authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers("/oauth/introspect").access("isAuthenticated()");

   }
```

Now Spring security kicks in but it doesn't treat this request the same way it does for `/oauth/check_token` and by that I mean it doesn't look up table oauth_client_details automatically just like the same way it does for other oauth related requests. As such, I get 401 http error code.

I think I am missing something here to tell Spring that this is oauth2 request so that it considers client-id/secret and authenticate it automatically. Any hint would be appreciated.

My configurations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorisationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MySecuritySettings securitySetting;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                //TODO I'd rather not to override Spring's endpoint URL but had issues with authentication. 
            .pathMapping("/oauth/check_token", "/oauth/introspect").tokenStore(this.tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenServices(tokenServices())
            .accessTokenConverter(tokenConverter())
            .requestValidator(createOAuth2RequestValidator());

    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(myClientDetailsService());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyClientDetailsService myClientDetailsService(){
        MyClientDetailsService myClientDetailsService = new MyClientDetailsService(dataSource);
        myClientDetailsService.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return myClientDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(tokenConverter());
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new CompJwtAccessTokenConverter();
        DefaultAccessTokenConverter defaultAccessTokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        defaultAccessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(new CompPrincipalExtractor());
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setAccessTokenConverter(defaultAccessTokenConverter);

        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                new ClassPathResource(securitySetting.getKeystoreFileName()),
                securitySetting.getStorepass().toCharArray())
                .getKeyPair(securitySetting.getKeyAlias(),
                        securitySetting.getKeypass().toCharArray());
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(securitySetting.isRefreshAccessToken());
        tokenServices.setReuseRefreshToken(securitySetting.isReuseRefreshToken());
        tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(tokenConverter());
        tokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(securitySetting.getAccessTokenValiditySeconds());
        return tokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public OAuth2RequestValidator createOAuth2RequestValidator() {
        return new ExpressionBasedOAuth2RequestValidator();
    }

}
```

AND this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "auth_serv";

    @Autowired
    TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    MySecuritySettings mySecuritySettings;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/introspect").access("isAuthenticated()")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**/*").access("#oauth2.hasScope('" + mySecuritySettings.getAuthserverScopenameAllAccess() + "')");
    }


}
```

Comment: @dur Sorry, I get unauthorised error... the message says full authentication is required. 401 http code. So if I send a request to /oauth/token to ask authorisation server to issue an access token, I can see the BasicAuthenticationFilter gets in and then finally JdbcClientDetailsService looks up the database for client Id and secret but for this request (URL /oauth/introspect)  it won’t. It’s weekend and I don’t have the code today

Comment: *`.antMatchers("/oauth/introspect").access("isAuthenticated()")`* is not needed, because it is not part of the resource server. It is part of the authorization server. And *`.pathMapping("/oauth/check_token", "/oauth/introspect")`* should be a conflict, because you have already a controller (`TokenIntrospectionEndpointImpl `) mapped to that URL. To map also `CheckTokenEndpoint` to that URL seems to be wrong.

Comment: Maybe you find a solution in one of these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405585/spring-oauth-override-checktokenendpoint-check-tokentoken-response-map and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298009/customizing-tokenendpoint-in-spring-oauth2.

Comment: @dur with this configuration it works fine... and that's because I am overriding /check_token to /introspect as you can see I put a TODO in there. But I am looking for a solution to avoid this approach. I'd like to add a new endpoint without overriding the spring's url mappings. If I remove that, I get 401 error for /introspect

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand your problem. You don't want to change the URL, it should still be `/token/check_access`. You want to override the `CheckTokenEndpoint`. In this case use `/token/check_access` as path for your custom controller, it will override the default controller `CheckTokenEndpoint`.